# Paypal Authorization standard and capture through REST API

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I've been asking myself if there is a possibility to use the standard payment page of paypal to redirect user to "Authorize" a payment using their Credit card (using "paymentaction" : "authorization" in the redirect form).
Having IPN setup i could receive the auth_id.
Then later on "Capture" an amount (equals or less) using the Paypal REST API but using the "auth_id" received through IPN ?
It seems the "authorization_id" received through Paypal REST API "Authorize" is the same length. Somehow i suppose it is the same value.

Before implementing such i wonder if anyone tried this before ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the standard (Website Payments Standard) page to creat the authorization paired with the "classic" authorization API, but you cannot mix the classic and REST APIs as you described.

The REST APIs store different/additional information on PayPal's server side, so in general you cannot manipulate transactions created through classic APIs via REST APIs (and vice versa is also complicated and generally not advised).